# Unable to cast int from b'0\n'

Tags: python, casting, int, byte, paramiko

I use `paramiko` ssh to run `cat /tmp/file` on a remote computer, which contains a single digit.

This digit needs to be compared with 0.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cat /tmp/file')
print("stdout:")
print(stdout)
print("\nstdout.read():")
print(stdout.read())
print("\nif not int(errlvl) == 0:")
errlvl = stdout.read()
if not int(errlvl) == 0:
```

Output:

```
stdout:
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 35 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x2b36750 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>

stdout.read():
b'0\n'

int(stdout.read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
    if not int(errlvl) == 0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b''
```

How can I use the `int` value, in this case `0`, in my `if`?

Comment: it's not `b'0\n'`, it's an empty bytestring `b''`.  `int(b'0\n')` works.

Comment: you're not printing the right thing. `print errlvl`

Comment: `stdout.read()` moves the file pointer, if you call it again, you'll get nothing.

Answer (score 3):

The code is calling `stdout.read` twice; causing the second read return empty bytes.

Read once and store it somewhere, and reuse it.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cat /tmp/file')
print("stdout:")
print(stdout)
print("\nstdout.read():")
errlvl= stdout.read()  # <-----
print(errlvl)
print("\nif not int(errlvl) == 0:")
if not int(errlvl) == 0:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
stdout.read()
```

will get you `b'0\n'`; but the *second* `stdout.read()` will get you an empty string, because the first `read()` has already read the `0`. `read()` doesn't read from the start, but where it last left.

This is also what the error says:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: b''
```

`b''`, not `b'0\n`.

so what you need to do is call `read()` once, and immediately store that in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading from stdout twice, thus leaving the second read empty instead of your anticipated '0\n' value. Do it like this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cat /tmp/file')
print("stdout:")
print(stdout)
print("\nstdout.read():")
errlvl = stdout.read()
print(errlvl)
print("\nif not int(errlvl) == 0:")
if not int(errlvl) == 0:
```